# Getting an automatic serialNumber from the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my project, I have to get a StudentId when the data is saved for the first time(technically INSERT command) from the database. Currently my stored proc for insertion is as follows:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_iSaveStudent]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StudentId varchar(50),
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @MiddleName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @CGPA decimal(18),
    @Email varchar(50)  
AS
BEGIN
    insert into dbo.Student values(@StudentId,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@CGPA,@Email)
END
```

I am passing NULL string for studentId while saving for the first time. Could anyone please suggest me how to generate an automatically incremented StudentId for each record I insert and simultaneously return that to my program ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try google by `automatically incremented`.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Hamlet Hakobyan.I got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SQL SERVER**, while creating your table use `IDENTITY(1,1)` function that will automatically increment to next value.

After insert query use `@@IDENTITY` variable to get the last identity value entered into a table in your current session

Something like

```
// Create your table
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)

//Create your procedure
create procedure myproc as
begin
insert into persons(lastname) values('jasdg');
print @@identity; // use this variable to get the last value generated
end
```

Although, you can also use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY`** instead of **`@@IDENTITY`**, so better visit [this blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) to use suitable one.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @jWeaver please be careful when giving advices, I'd say @@identity is pretty dangerous to use in this situation

Comment: @RomanPekar agree, that's why I said better visit that blog to use appropriate one :)

Comment: I got that auto incremented,but still it doesn't return me the last inserted value. Any suggestions .The query:AS BEGIN insert into dbo.Student values(@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@CGPA,@Email) SET @StudentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() END

Comment: what about `@StudentId` ?? where are you retrieving this variable ??

Comment: @jWeaver,Yeah, I forgot to post that. I ended up with "Select @StudentId" at last.I should have posted that as well earlier.